# UICollectionViewController item insert animation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, core-animation

Been trying to animate the item insert on a collection view, the animation is a slide in from outside of the screen from left to right or right to left, for that I'am changing the item's frame origin x value.

[image]

My problem is when I call UIView.animate the completion callback is called instantaneously not showing the animation, I've tried to add the animation code inside the item's class, inside the method collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) and even tried to create a custom viewflowlayout and override the layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath to add a transformation, but none of that worked, any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        var newFrame = cell.frame
        cell.frame = CGRect(x: newFrame.origin.x + 50, y: newFrame.origin.y, width: newFrame.width, height: newFrame.height)
    })
}
```

Replace the offset as per your need.

Also this works too:

```
cell.frame.origin.x = cell.frame.origin.x + 50
```

inside of the willDisplayCell

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion is not the cleanest way, had to implement controls to avoid repeating the animation, but it works.

Comment: You can have a property in your cell, set that property in dequeReusableCell. In the willDisplayCell check for this property and call the animation. I am not entirely adapt with your implementation, let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks again, I did something a little different because of my code. What I didn't understand was the fact that I didn't need to use UIView,animate just adding a something like this cell.transform = transform was enough to make the animation, strange.